# Breaking the security inheritance of a site (SharePoint, C#)

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

The following code snippet breaks the security inheritance of a list.

```
        string siteUrl = "http://MyServer/sites/MySiteCollection";
        ClientContext oContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
        SP.List oList = oContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Announcements");

        oList.BreakRoleInheritance(true, false);

        oContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

How can I do the same for a site? Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535228.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can use:

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
web.BreakRoleInheritance(true, false);
```

Reference: [SPWeb.BreakRoleInheritance Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee547386.aspx)